# How can i add values to count in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

[image]

I have following SQL Query related at the ER-Diagram shown in the image.

```
Select count(distinct(tkey)) as fromAustria 
from theses 
where ikey in (select ikey 
               from institutions 
                   right join countries on institutions.cokey = countries.cokey 
               where countries.name = 'Austria');
```

How can I retrieve this information?

**How many distinct theses and papers did persons currently affiliated with Austrian
institutions publish? (return single count)**

I always have the distinct theses, but how can i add to the count the distinct papers?

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. If there is no direct key relationship between the 'papers' and 'theses' tables, you will need to go through the 'authpapers' table

```
Select count(distinct(tkey)) as fromAustria, count(distinct(pkey)) as papers
from theses
Left/Inner/right join Authpapers on authpapers.key = theses.key
Left/Inner/right join papers on  papers.key = authpapers.key
where ikey in (select ikey 
               from institutions 
                   right join countries on institutions.cokey = countries.cokey 
               where countries.name = 'Austria');
```